# Ember, observers trigger in a strange order

Tags: javascript, select, binding, ember.js

Here's my controller `EventTimezoneController`. Its `content` property is set to an `Event` model.

```
App.ChallengeTimezoneController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    timezones: [{value: "", label: ""}, {...}]

    timezoneDidChange: (->
        console.log "In controller", @get("timezone")
    ).observes("timezone") # I also tried "content.timezone"
```

And now my `Event` model:

```
App.Event = App.Challenge = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations,
    timezone: DS.attr('string')

    timezoneDidChange: (->
        console.log "In model", @get("timezone")
    ).observes("timezone")
)
```

And then, I have a `TimezoneSelect` view

```
App.TimezoneSelect = Ember.Select.extend
  valueBinding: "controller.timezone"
  contentBinding: "controller.timezones"
  optionValuePath: "content.value",
  optionLabelPath: "content.label"
```

---

**Now here's the problem**: when I select a new value in the select dropdown, the log shows:

```
> In controller American Samoa
> In model American Samoa
```

Why is the method `timezoneDidChange` from the controller called before the one in the model, since from what I understand, it's observing a property of the model?

Comment: It's a typo or are you missing the `->` in `timezoneDidChange:` in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ember.js`, controllers are meant to *proxy* model, so it makes sense to call the computed properties function on the controller first. For reference you can check out this very informative [talk from Luke Melia at Ember.js NYC](http://youtube.com/watch?v=7O9X5oeAJm4) especially [at min 31:30](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O9X5oeAJm4&t=31m30s) where a slide is shown with the concept.

hope it helps

Comment: I see what you mean. It's just that I was triggering a save in the method `timezoneDidChange` from the controller. And what's happening is that, at that time, the timezone value changed, but it's not been registered by the model state manager yet, which cause the transaction to fail and other problems...